# Umbraco 7 Custom Section with grandchildren in list-view

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco7

I am trying to build a custom section for Umbraco. My end goal is that it look like the following

```
-MyCustomSection
   -Subsection1(with children in listview)
   -Subsection2(with children in listview)
```

I cannot find any Umbraco documentation on how I would...

- Have grandchildren nodes
- Have children nodes in a list-view

I have gone through every tutorial, but none of them tell you how you can turn on list-view or how you can add nodes under your children nodes.

Any help would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation here: 
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Extending/Section-Trees/trees-v7  - it should get you going with child nodes etc.

As for ListView, it's essentially a DataType with a special implementation in the Content/Member edit forms (when configured to do so) - you can achieve the same thing with your own custom node editor but the best documentation for that is the source code itself.

Depending on how you're building your custom section, you may find yourself implementing a custom ListView as well if you're not just rendering Content/Media etc.

Take a look also at the [MemberListView](https://github.com/robertjf/umbMemberListView3) project - it's a custom ListView implementation and the source may shed some light on things for you; it's using Examine to retrieve the data instead of the database in most cases for performance sake, but the concepts in there are the same for the most part.

Hope this helps, you'll have some heavy code reading ahead of you I think; and it would be worth compiling in debug and running Umbraco setting breakpoints along the way as well.